# How get all the keys of secureStorage with ionic 2?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to get all the keys stored in my secureStorage.

https://github.com/Crypho/cordova-plugin-secure-storage

Then I have write a service with functions like:

```
getValue(item): any {
    return <Promise<any>> this.secureStorage.get(item);
}
```

That works fine with Android, but with iOs it give an error:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Failure in SecureStorage.get() - The specified item could not be found in the keychain
```

I throught that the error came, when I do a get, for example:

```
this.myService.getValue('item1').then(
                        (data) => {
console.log(data);
});
```

If I understand, in the keychain, there are no value item1, but how can I test if a value exists before doing a get?

In the documentation, it's a keys function, which has to give me all the keys. But this function don't work for me:

```
getAllKeys(item): any {
     <Promise<any>> this.secureStorage.keys();
}
```

That give for me a:

```
this.myService.keys is not a function
```

I'm using ionic 2.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: are you using ionic native? if so which version?

Comment: Yes, version 2.2.11